# Applying buttonStyle via theme wouldn't work, applying directly works perfectly

Tags: android, android-theme

I am having problem applying button style to the theme but applying to the button directly works perfectly. Any idea what's the problem here?

**themes.xml**

```
<style name="Theme.AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.Sherlock.Light.DarkActionBar">
    <item name="android:buttonStyle">@style/ButtonAppTheme</item>
</style>
```

**styles.xml**

```
<style name="ButtonAppTheme" parent="@android:style/Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_default_holo_light</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">64dip</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#000000</item>
</style>
```

**AndroidManifest.xml**

```
<Application
    android:name=".ThreesixtyusApp"
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@drawable/icon"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppTheme" >
```

Applying button style directly works:

```
  <Button
      android:id="@+id/like"
      android:layout_width="100dp"
      android:layout_height="wrap_content"
      style="@style/ButtonAppTheme"
      android:text="@string/like" />
```

Comment: May be activity has attribute "theme" and it overrides application theme?

Comment: This looks generated. Did you forget about the styles/themes in the values-v11 or values-v14 folders?

Comment: @Krylez Thanks! that solved the problem, you should post that as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks generated. Did you forget about the styles/themes in the values-v11 or values-v14 folders?